# Count the number of images using import.io

Tags: xpath, import.io

I have tried using XPath's `count()` to get the number of images on a slider. For example:

```
count(//*[@id="slider"]/div/ul/li/img)
```

It works when I use an XPath tester (XPath Helper extension for Chrome), but not when using import.io which leads me to believe it does not support `count()`. Is there a different way to get a count of the number of images?

Comment: Hi, Yes we do support count() on the import.io browser. It could be several things that are causing this xpath not to work, but we will need more information. For help with specific websites, it is best to contact support@import.io and supply the website and GUID so we can test it.

Comment: Have you found a solution ? I'm facing the same problem. I'm trying to count the number of cells in a row with `count(./td)` but nothing is extracted.

Comment: I haven't. I tried different websites and counting different things but it appears to simply not be supported. I did just open an idea/suggestion at support.import.io, but it's awaiting moderator approval.
http://support.import.io/forums/199278-ideas-forum/suggestions/10599426-be-able-to-use-count

Comment: beware that if the document you are trying to parse is not well formed (e.g. some tags not closed), this may prevent the xpath to work properly